# How to get ConversionValue from google adwords api v2001502

Tags: php, google-ads-api

I've downloaded the PHP client library for Google Adwords API. I need to fetch 'ConversionsManyPerClick' data from the api, I can't find an option for the same from the client library. But the same time i am able to take this data as file by using this 'AD_PERFORMANCE_REPORT' method. Please help me.

```
    function DownloadCriteriaReportExample(AdWordsUser $user, $filePath) {
      // Load the service, so that the required classes are available.
      $user->LoadService('ReportDefinitionService');

      // Create selector.
      $selector = new Selector();

      $selector->fields = array('Headline','Description1','Description2','DisplayUrl','AdGroupName','CampaignName','Clicks','ConversionsManyPerClick');

      $selector->predicates[] = new Predicate('Status', 'NOT_IN', array('PAUSED'));

      $reportDefinition = new ReportDefinition();
      $reportDefinition->selector = $selector;
      $reportDefinition->reportName = 'ad performance report #' . uniqid();
      $reportDefinition->dateRangeType = 'LAST_30_DAYS';
      $reportDefinition->reportType = 'AD_PERFORMANCE_REPORT';
      $reportDefinition->downloadFormat = 'CSV';

      $reportDefinition->includeZeroImpressions = FALSE;

      $options = array('version' => 'v201502');

      ReportUtils::DownloadReport($reportDefinition, $filePath, $user, $options);
    }
```

[image]
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Please read the following documentation and also try to modify the core plugin

https://developers.google.com/adwords/api/docs/guides/conversion-tracking